# MIPS buffer content not printing

Tags: assembly, mips

Solved: I moved both files to Desktop and it worked - I guess some directories on mac have permission issues.

I am trying to print out the contents of a text file (test1.txt) that is in the same directory as my MARS file but the contents of the buffer isn't printing. The string in the test file just contains letters and no NULL characters. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
.data
file: .asciiz "test1.txt"      # filename for input
buffer: .space 128


.text
    #li $t0, 0 # bracket counter
    #la $s0, theArray #pointer the string


        li   $v0, 13          # system call for open file
    la   $a0, file       # input file name
    li   $a1, 0           # flag for reading
    li   $a2, 0           # mode is ignored
    syscall               # open a file 
    move $s0, $v0         # save the file descriptor  


    # reading from file just opened 

    li   $v0, 14        # system call for reading from file
    move $a0, $s0       # file descriptor 
    la   $a1, buffer    # address of buffer from which to read
    li   $a2,  11     # hardcoded buffer length
    syscall             # read from file


    li  $v0, 4         # system Call for PRINT STRING
    la  $a0, ($a1)      # buffer contains the values
    syscall  


    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall #closes file

    li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: When you single-step in the MARS debugger, what's the return value of each system call?  (look at `$v0` after each syscall instruction).  And check memory contents of the buffer.

Comment: Nothing because it wasn't opening the file up at all. I fixed it however - turns out on mac some directories (like Documents where I was storing both files) has permission issues so I moved both the code file and text file to my desktop and it worked!

Comment: Every system call has a return value.  It might be a special value that indicates an error like permission denied or file not found, which is exactly why I was suggesting that.  https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html says syscall 13 (open) returns a file descriptor, or *negative if error*.